# WP7 Application Life Time Funcitons

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have created a custom Class Library(named it as MiEngine), in that I have created an Application class(MiEngineApp.xaml and MiEngineApp.xaml.cs). In my project(application), I have integrated the Class Library and my project's App class extends the Class Library's Application class(ie. public partial class App:MiEngineApp). I have made changes in the App.xaml also using the z name space.

I want to implement the Application life cycle methods only in the Class Library's Application class not in the project's Appication class. But If I do not implement the Application Life cycle methods in the project's Application class, at run time XamlParseException is thrown in the MiEngineApp.g.i.cs file's InitializeComponent method. I have no clue why this happens and how to implement the life cycle methods only in the Class library's Application class. Please give me some idea!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could put the logic for the lifecycle events in the library and then call them from the event handlers in the (each?) app. Yes this means adding 4 lines of code to the app but this is the best solution currently available.

As per the default comments in app.xaml, handlers for the `Launching`, `Activated`, `Deactivated` and `Closing` events of the `PhoneApplicationService` are **REQUIRED**.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!. I have a doubt. I have added handlers for all these four life cycle events in the Class Library itself. Can you tell me why those are not getting called ? Why we need to implement the handlers in the project's App.xaml.cs ?.

Comment: The framework will try and call the events in the application. They are required. It won't look for them anywhere else.